# Android fragment transaction animation is not working on view pager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmenttransaction

I create an android app using `ViewPager` and `Fragments` . In here I use `FragmentTransaction`to sliding fragments among each other using a button action. Also I use a method to shifting among fragments . It is in MainActivity class.

This is MainActivity class,

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter2(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                    return true;
                }

                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
                    return true;
                }

                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
                    return true;
                }

                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 3) {
                    return true;
                }

                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 4) {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });



    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter2 extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter2(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {

                case 0: return FirstFragment1.newInstance("FirstFragment_1");
                case 1: return SecondFragment1.newInstance("SecondFragment_1");
                case 2: return ThirdFragment1.newInstance("ThirdFragment_1");
                case 3: return FourthFragment1.newInstance("FourthFragment_1");
                case 4: return FifthFragment1.newInstance("FifthFragment_1");
                default: return FirstFragment1.newInstance("DefaultFragment_1");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }
    }

    public void setCurrentItem(int which) {
        if(viewPager != null && which >= 0 && which <= 4) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(which);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is an sample code for my purpose,

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by user on 5/11/2016.
 */
public class SecondFragment1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_frag_1, container, false);

        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragSecond);
        tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));


        Button button=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.printButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(getActivity() != null) {

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.from_right, R.anim.to_left);
                    FirstFragment1 firstFragment1=FirstFragment1.newInstance("Fragment Main");
                    transaction.replace(R.id.firstFragment, firstFragment1, "first_fragment");
                    transaction.commit();

                    ( (MainActivity)getActivity()).setCurrentItem(0);
                }

            }
        });

        Button button1=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (getActivity() != null) {
                    ( (MainActivity)getActivity()).setCurrentItem(2); // fourth fragment index is 3
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    public static SecondFragment1 newInstance(String text) {

        SecondFragment1 f = new SecondFragment1();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser) {
            Activity a = getActivity();
            if(a != null) a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
        }
    }

}
```

These are my animation files ,

**from_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

**from_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

**to_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

**to_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

Problem :- When use this animation files to shift among fragments is not working .

When I click on **button** in **SecondFragment1** , 0 th fragment should load to the `ViewPager` from right to left direction . But , the process is difference in here . First , 0th fragment load to the `ViewPager` from left to right direction then again it load from right to left direction .

My purpose is load 0th fragment to the `ViewPager` from right to left direction at the begining .

How could I get this in a correct view ? Have any ideas ?

Thanks in deep.

Comment: Are you using fragment transactions to change the page on the viewpager? And do you need to be able to swipe the viewpager to change fragments?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand by the question you just want to replace the fragment when a button is pressed? So to start with I would remove the view pager and replace it with a FrameLayout.

Declare framelayout at top of class:

```
FrameLayout fl_frag_container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fl_frag_container);
```

Then create a method in the MainActivity you can call from the fragment to change the fragment being displayed:

In my case i use:

```
public void setSecondaryFrag(int page, String name, String url, String id) {
    transaction = fragMan.beginTransaction();
    switch (page) {
        case Constants.VIEW_EVENTS:
            transaction.replace(fl_frag_container.getId(), new ViewEventsFragment());
            break;
        case Constants.VIEW_ARTIST_PROFILE:
            transaction.replace(fl_frag_container.getId(), BrandArtistProfileFragment.newInstance(Constants.ARTISTS, name, url, id));
            break;
        case Constants.VIEW_BRAND_PROFILE:
            transaction.replace(fl_frag_container.getId(), BrandArtistProfileFragment.newInstance(Constants.BRANDS,name, url, id) );
            break;
        case Constants.VIEW_TICKETS:
            transaction.replace(fl_frag_container.getId(), new ViewTicketFragment());
            break;

    }
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.from_right, R.anim.to_left);
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

And then in the fragment i would call

```
((MainActivity) getActivity).setSecondaryFrag(page, "", "", "");
```

This can be modified to suit your needs

Using the frame layout to replace the fragments removes the need to use adapters for the viewpager

Hope this helps

Comment: I have to use ViewPager . It is a requirement of the app . Thanks for the help . And do you have another idea ?

Comment: Does the user need to be able to swipe between fragments?

Comment: In some cases , they want this privilege .

Comment: have a look at this SO post to do with overriding the viewpager animation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129847/android-viewpager-with-different-animation-like-zoom-in-fade-etc

Comment: Ok , I will look at.

Answer (score 1):

If you require that a viewpager is used then look at this SO post to do with overriding the viewpager animation

[Android ViewPager With different Animation like zoom in,fade etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129847/android-viewpager-with-different-animation-like-zoom-in-fade-etc)