# Transition between 3 ImageViews placed one after another

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation, android-transitions

I am working on an application which shows the Most recent active users in group. It is being shown by 3 ImageViews having the display images of the users. When a new user other than one in the present 3 becomes active he must be shown in the first imageview with FadeIn animation and the last one must be fadeout. the other two must be shifting to next Imageviews. I want to know how should I make a transition animation between those ImageViews.

Edit : 
Images are not bigger ones. This will be similar to fb messenger. When ever a new user becomes active his image must be displayed with the above transition.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use viewpager and apply animation, refer below link for more details

[Android ViewPager With different Animation like zoom in,fade etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129847/android-viewpager-with-different-animation-like-zoom-in-fade-etc)